phpunit inject mocked object into another mocked object
I want to test the output of method checkCredentials():
Class BuildParticipant
{
    public function __construct(DBConnectionWrapper $db, ?Logger $logger=null)
    {
        $this->participant = new ParticipantView($db);
        // snip
    }

    public function build($participantId)
    {
       $credentialsOK = $this->checkCredentials($participantId, $this->participant);
       // snip
    }
 
    protected function checkCredentials($participantId, Crud $participant): bool
    {
        $data = $participant->find($participantId)->nextRecord();
        // do some logic on $data and return boolean

My original way of writing the function was not very testable:
    protected function checkCredentials($participantId): bool
    {
        $data = $this->participant->find($participantId)->nextRecord();

I figured that injecting ParticipantView into the method would allow me to inject a mock ParticipantView::find()
I'm having trouble crafting the mock (or stub - not sure about terminology)
<?php
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class buildNewParticipantTest extends TestCase {
    public function testCredentialInclusion()
    {
        $mockDb = $this->getMockBuilder('Database')->getMock();

        // unsuccessful attempt to fix error in test (ParticipantView is a CrudView)
        $participantView = new ParticipantView($mockDb);

        $pv = $this
                ->getMockBuilder($participantView::class)
                ->onlyMethods(['find'])
                ->getMock();

        $pv
            ->expects($this->once())
            ->method('find')
            ->willReturn([
                'id'        => '1234',
                'ssn'       => '555-12-3456',
                'lastName'  => 'Smith',
                'firstName' => 'John',
                'credentials' => 'foo' 
            ]);

        $this->assertEquals('John', $pv['firstName']);
    }
}

yields
There was 1 error:

1) buildNewParticipantTest::testCredentialInclusion
ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function CrudView::__construct(), 0 passed

How do I pass a mock Database object into the mock ParticipantView object?
Edit
I realized that I didn't give enough information for the error to make sense.  All of the objects refer to getting information from the database (no presentation logic).
abstract class DBConnectionWrapper
{

class DB_ODBC extends DBConnectionWrapper
{

class Database extends DB_ODBC 
{

class Crud implements CrudDefinition
{
    public function __construct(DBConnectionWrapper $db, ?Monolog\Logger $log = null)
    {

/**
 * CRUD View
 *
 * A CrudView accesses a query as if it were a table, so that we can
 * combine several tables into a single table and use Crud methods on
 * it.
 *
 * Read Only!
 */
class CrudView extends Crud
{
    public function __construct(DBConnectionWrapper $db)
    {
        parent::__construct($db);
        // do other stuff...

class ParticipantView extends CrudView 
{

So, normally ParticipantView is instantiated with
$db = new Database();
$pv = new ParticipantView($db);



How do I pass a mock Database object into the mock ParticipantView object?

In general you do it with dependency injection by injecting the DatabaseMock into the ParticipantView (Mock). It is a constructor parameter.
The difference to new is, that you have to tell it the mocker, and that should already do it, you can specify constructor parameters when mocking the ParticipantView::class. See Chapter 9: Test Doubles.
Why am I lazy adding a short code example here? I stumbled over the class-name: ParticipantView. And so I thought before I give you all the cool codes (the PHPUnit manual does a far better job anyway), I was thinking: Should a view object have a database connection? And this reminded me on one of my early webapps (and successful working for years application) where I had a similar setup (but no tests). And even I would not want to miss the learnings from that project, I cannot suggest to do that. Better have the data-binding to a view much more lightweight, especially when writing object oriented code under unit tests.
Why? you may ask now. Because a view does not need more. You may want to allow types for data points and iterables of different kinds for lists into the view layer, but this should be kept simple and generic so that the view layer can flourish.
And another reason is, that since I started with unit testing and TDD in specific, it helped me to find better designs. And next to skill issue not knowing how to create the correct mock, there is also the learning that if I needed to create many mocks in tests, this was not a good and healthy to maintain thing. Writing such tests always was the more fine-grained learning where the subject under test was not (yet) having the right design, so I changed it while writing the tests. This I don't want to hide from you in my answer. Writing the tests before the code nearly entirely prevents mocking while it allows to see and create a bigger picture. Despite only writing units.

My well-thought-out naming convention for referring to Database Views (as opposed to tables) apparently wasn't so well thought out since I made you stumble.  I can certainly see where that name sent you down the wrong path.  Naming things is such fun ;) ParticipantView is a read-only DAO, which must have the database connection injected into it.

Hehe, you've caught me fully misled by that. Okay, then the lower part of the answer might be interesting but not that much of the issue. Now as I know about that, maybe I find some time later to review my answer and edit it. Cheers!

With the testing, it is usually more approachable to focus on the behavior (aka public interfaces) rather than on implementation details (non-public interfaces). Implementation details tend to change more often than general behavior as a whole.
There is nothing untestable in your original approach for the implementation of the method as it should not affect the test. Otherwise, your test is too coupled with the implementation, and it might be difficult and tedious to maintain.
If you have the opportunity I suggest having ParticipantView and possibly other DAO if you have something in the constructor as a dependency. It makes it easier to set up Mocks or other TestDoubles and allows you to focus on public interfaces.
class BuildParticipant
{
    public function __construct(
        ParticipantView $participant,
        /** other DAO */
        ?Logger $logger=null
    ) {
        $this->participant = $participant;
        // snip
    }
    // ...
}

Partially mock code under the test can bring challenges and make your code and test coupled in a way, that might be difficult to untangle and support. I suggest avoiding it, when possible.
Back to your original question: I couldn't find a way to override an argument for a method with the mock library, maybe it's there, maybe not... You could decorate the method, and pass the expected TestDouble into it during the test, but I wouldn't recommend it.
final class BuildParticipantW extends BuildParticipant
{
    public function __construct(
        /** BuildParticipant dependencies */
        ParticipantView $mockParticipantView
    ) {
        parent::__constructor(/** dependencies */);
        $this->mockParticipantView = $mockParticipantView;
    }

    protected function checkCredentials($participantId, Crud $participant): bool
    {
        return parent::checkCredentials($participantId, $this->mockParticipantView);
    }
    // ...
}

